# Magento 2 Admin Url Redirecting to Homepage with index.php

Tags: magento2, admin

Magento 2 Admin Url Redirecting to Homepage with index.php

my admin name is admin

```
https://www.muzikhausberlin.de/admin
```

when i enter this it goes to

```
https://www.muzikhausberlin.de/index.php
```

any once can advice?

Comment: What do you have in database table core_config_data in row web/cookie/cookie_domain???

Comment: there is no such row  web/cookie/cookie_domain

Comment: in tabel  core_config_data  there is path web/cookie/cookie_domain and please read value that is assigned to this row.

Comment: may be something with your web browser. Try with another browser or private browser